# How can I apply different css to different child elements in css?

Tags: html, css

Below is my html code -

```css
.parent>.textClass:first-child {
  margin-top: -1rem;
}

.parent>.textClass:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: -3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <section class="sectionWrapper">
      <div class="textClass">
        <span>My text</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <section class="sectionWrapper">
      <div class="textClass">
        <span>My text</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <section class="sectionWrapper">
      <div class="textClass">
        <span>My text</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want first `textClass` should be `marginTop:-1px;` and then rest `textClass` should be `marginTop:-3px;`. I tried to do below code but it's not working -

How can I apply css on different child elements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.textClass` is not a child to `.parent`. It is a grandchild.

Use this:

**note:** I changed your margin to a positive margin so you can see the changes. With the negative margin set, it was going out of the viewport.

```css
.parent>div:first-child > section > .textClass {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.parent> div:not(:first-child) > section > .textClass {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <section class="sectionWrapper">
      <div class="textClass">
        <span>My text</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <section class="sectionWrapper">
      <div class="textClass">
        <span>My text</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  <div>
    <section class="sectionWrapper">
      <div class="textClass">
        <span>My text</span>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is trying to target direct children to parent with the ">".

I'm not sure if the classes are used for anything else on the site but if not I would skip the direct child selector. I'm also not sure why you have "empty" divs as "wrappers"? If there is no specific thought behind it I would do the following.

```css
.sectionWrapper .textClass {
  margin-top: -3rem;
}

.sectionWrapper:first-child .textClass {
  margin-top: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <section class="sectionWrapper">
    <div class="textClass">
      <span>My text</span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="sectionWrapper">
    <div class="textClass">
      <span>My text</span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="sectionWrapper">
    <div class="textClass">
      <span>My text</span>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

If you really want to "optimise" your html/css I would use more direct and specific class instead of "nesting" selectors.

```css
.section-wrapper__text {
  margin-top: -3rem;
}

.section_wrapper:first-child > .section-wrapper__text {
  margin-top: -1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <section class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="section-wrapper__text">
      <span>My text</span>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="section-wrapper__text">
      <span>My text</span>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```